# Select Layer by Location - Arcpy - Why are my inputs being interpreted as invalid?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-toolbox, error-000368

I am working on a tool in a python toolbox and am totally confused about what is going on and causing my select by location operation to fail (Error 000368).

I am trying to select the features in one layer that are completely within a specific polygon.
Here is the line where the error is occuring:

```
for (index,item) in enumerate(TempIDs):         
    lyrBoundaries.definitionQuery = "[" + parameters[1].valueAsText + "]" + " = " + "'" + str(item) + "'"

    for (index2,item2) in enumerate(Spec_Layers):
        currentLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(str(item2))

        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(currentLayer,"WITHIN",lyrBoundaries)

        arcpy.CalculateField_management(currentLayer,parameters[3].valueAsText,hopper,"VB","#")
```

The error is occurring in the arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management() line.  The text of the error message I'm getting is: (edited to remove the actual text of the path)

```
    Executing: SelectLayerByLocation "[FULL PATH OF currentLayer]" COMPLETELY_WITHIN GPL0 "0 Unknown" NEW_SELECTION
Start Time: Fri Mar 01 10:29:29 2013
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
```

My question is really: *Why is lyrBoundaries showing up as GPL0 and not as the path of the layer?*  Beyond that, any tips or hints about why the inputs are being interpreted as invalid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized that my problem was coming from the extra step of trying to dynamically recreate a layer for every entry in Spec_Layers.  This value was being set from a multivalue input in the tool, which returns a list of objects which are already instantiated as Layer objects (so, no need to make a layer out of a layer).

This is working for me nicely: (parameters[2].values is the list of Layer objects returned from the list of Layers chosen in the tool dialog box)

```
for (index,item) in enumerate(TempIDs):

lyrBoundaries.definitionQuery = "[" + parameters[1].valueAsText + "]" + " = " + "'" + str(item) + "'"

messages.addMessage("Associating Data for: " + str(lyrBoundaries.definitionQuery))

for (index2,item2) in enumerate(parameters[2].values):

    #Select all of the features in the current layer that are completely within the current Site Boundary
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(item2,"WITHIN",lyrBoundaries)

    #Set hopper equal to the current value of TempID
    hopper = '"' + str(item) + '"'
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(item2,parameters[3].valueAsText,hopper,"VB","#")
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you create currentlayer using arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer instead of arcpy.mapping.Layer.